# Is possible to add a callback to any function in php?

Tags: php, callback

Can I add a callback to a php native function?

```
on('json_encode',function(){
    echo "encoding something";
});
```

If yes,  is it possible to add a post and pre callback?
Thank you.

Comment: No! Only when the PHP Docs for a function say that it accepts a callback argument, such as `array_filter()` or `usort()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you would have to rewrite your own wrapper function. Something like:

```
function my_json_encode($data) {
    if (function_exists("json_encode_pre_callback")) {
        json_encode_pre_callback();
    }
    $return = json_encode($data);
    if (function_exists("json_encode_post_callback")) {
        json_encode_post_callback($return);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Or, using callback as a parameter:

```
function my_json_encode($data, $pre = null, $post = null) {
    if (is_callable($pre)) {
        $pre();
    }
    $return = json_encode($data);
    if (is_callable($post)) {
        $post($return);
    }
    return $return;
}

my_json_encode(
    $data,
    function(){echo "doing encode";},
    function($d){echo "done encode, value 1 is $d[1]";}
)
```

Comment: This COULD be made to accept the function name as a parameter, rather than hard-coded "pre" and "post" callbacks.

Comment: That's true, and recent PHP anonymous functions make that nicer to implement. I'll edit to include it.

Comment: Hello! I see what you do. But it wont work for me. I need something that doesnot need to change functions names. I want to add a single file at the start of the script and add callbacks to some functions. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Well I figured if I posted an answer that said "No" it wouldn't be very helpful. So I said "No" and also provided a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

No, the best way to do it would be a user defined function that calls the PHP native function.

Although, you can use `override_function` (see docs [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.override-function.php)) to redefine a PHP native function but please note that the `apd` extension is [not maintained anymore](https://pecl.php.net/package/apd).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I knew this function, but the problem is that I would have to make my users install the apd extension. And I dont want that. Thank you anway!

Comment: Also [`runkit_function_redefine()`](http://no2.php.net/runkit_function_redefine), but again this is an external library.